# OGR, writing TAB files, and BOUNDS

Tags: geoserver, mapinfo, tab

According to this: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mitab.html the TAB file writer sets default bounds, with the caveat that 'we should fix this'.

Bounds causes issues with respect to coordinate precision, see here: http://www.dse.vic.gov.au/property-titles-and-maps/maps-imagery-and-data/data/vicmap/datums-and-coordinate-systems/victorian-bounding-box

I would like to know if anyone knows how I can set bounds using OGR, and specifically, with GeoServer's WFS export using the OGR driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install at least GDAL 2.0 and then you can use the OGR Extension with the Layer Creation Options BOUNDS.

First install the OGR Extension 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/ogr.html

Then edit the ogr2ogr.xml so your MapInfo File Format looks like this:

```
<Format>
  <ogrFormat>MapInfo File</ogrFormat>
  <formatName>OGR-TAB</formatName>
  <fileExtension>.tab</fileExtension>
  <option>-lco</option>
  <option>BOUNDS=-500000,5000000,1500000,7000000</option>
</Format>
```

Comment: 4 years later, we have a solution!!!